# PHP удалённое подключение к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

положил страницу с вот таким php скриптом на **удалённый** хостинг.

```
$link = new mysqli('192.168.1.66', 'root', 'пароль', 'mainDB');
if ($link->connect_error) die("Ошибка: " . $link->connect_error);

$result = $link->query("SELECT sensorValue FROM sensors WHERE id=1;");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo (row['sensorValue']);
```

если обратиться по этому ip в браузере вижу свою страничку "It works!" из апача.

база данных с таким именем есть, таблица такая есть, через терминал этот запрос исполняется правильно.

не понимаю почему не могу подключиться **к своей** БД удалённо.

на страницу выводится следующее:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /storage/ssd1/482/8221482/public_html/index.php on line 12
Ошибка: Connection timed out
```

P.S строка 12 соответствует первой в этом вопросе; у меня Ubuntu 18.04

*ПК подключен к сети через wi-fi роутер, провайдер Билайн*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87218/discussion-on-question-by---php----mysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Разобрался.**
Проблема фактически заключалась в том, что не мог найти **белый IP** по которому можно было бы обратиться к моему компьютеру извне.
нашёл локальный IP моего ПК внутри своей домашней сети, нашёл IP роутера внутри сети от свича, нашёл даже IP свича, но он тоже оказался **в диапазоне локальных**
а виной всему один белый IP для множества клиентов Билайна (у меня просто не было **выделенного** IP). подключил услугу постоянный ip, выделили мне свой отдельный никем больше не используемый ip адрес. он же определился как внешний по отношению к роутеру. и вот он уже **белый**) соответственно после проведения некоторых манипуляций по настройке прав доступа к моей базе данных и указания в скрипте нового ip всё прекрасно заработало

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы видите в браузере страничку "It works!", ничего не говорит о доступности MySQL из вне. Страничка генерируется web-сервером (Apache, Nginx или др.) на 80 порту. MySQL-сервер, скорее всего, расположен на порту 3306 и через браузер вы к нему подключиться никак не сможете, даже если укажете порт в строке ввода URL, так как MySQL сервер использует другой протокол передачи данных.

Вы можете проверить есть ли подключение к БД с помощью терминала и команды Telnet:

```
telnet 94.130.120.65 3306
```

Если подключение будет удачно - на экране отобразятся строки с "крокозяблами", среди которых будет слово "MySQL".

Но скорее всего доступ из вне к серверу БД у хостинг-провайдера закрыт - обычно так поступает большинство хостингов. Также, MySQL сервер может располагаться на другом IP, отличном от того, на котором у вас лежит сайт. Обратитесь к своему хостинг-провайдеру и спросите, можете ли вы подключиться к MySQL-серверу напрямую со своего компьютера, попросите открыть вам доступ и выслать учетные данные - они могут отличаться от тех, что вы используете на сайте для доступа к БД.